Utility of longterm fee estimation
I've been reviewing the effectiveness of long-term fee estimation in Bitcoin Core and recently conducted an analysis, which indicates that it might not work as expected.
https://hackmd.io/@VzfUhtefQky1-i2_EY1HEQ/SyqBhQ8FR
Currently, Bitcoin Core seems to be the only provider offering long-term fee estimates for confirmation targets ranging from 2 to 1008 blocks. Most other services focus on 'as soon as possible' fee estimates, which appears to be the predominant use case.
Are there any specific protocols or users who actively rely on long-term fee estimation?
